# How can i increase page load timeout of selenium chrome driver

Tags: java, c#, google-chrome, selenium, driver

I use chrome driver for uploading files to remote server and this process sometimes takes more than 30 minutes as usual. I set the page load timeout value as below.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600); // 1 hour (C#)
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

But when i start uploading process, the chromedriver waits for a max of 10 minutes before it gives up saying that it doesn't get any response from the renderer.
Is there any way to increase this built-in timeout value (10 min).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this
`driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`;

here is the api.
[enter link description here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your suggestion is in java and equivalent to my line of code. driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800); // 30 min (C#)

Comment: @James Don't use tag `java` if you don't want suggestions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in your question about *using chrome driver for uploading files to remote server and this process sometimes takes more than 30 minutes as usual* and you have tried to increase the *page load timeout value* as follows :

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
```

First of all ***ChromeDriver*** and ***Chrome*** combination is yet to be ***W3C Complaint*** so you may experience some deviations from your overridden configuration. Comparatively ***GeckoDriver*** seems to be more ***W3C Complaint*** and here are some details :

*GeckoDriver* when started in default configuration sets the following **timeouts** :

- **`implicit`** : **0**
- **`pageLoad`** : **300000**
- **`script`** : **30000**

Now, while preparing your *Automation Scripts* you can override the default configuration for each of these **timeouts** which will be applicable throughout the lifetime of the *WebDriver* instance as you did in your code block :

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
```

As per the current [*WebDriver W3C Candidate Recommendation*](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#set-timeouts), the value for each of these **timeouts** can be extended till [*the maximum safe integer*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.max_safe_integer).

```
The value of Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is 9007199254740991 (2(pow)53−1).
```

> **Note** : Increasing the ***page load timeout value*** to wait for uploading files to remote server  won't be a part of *Best Programming Practices*. Instead you must create a logic which will determine the completion of *File Upload*. But this topic would be out of scope for this question.